# Salesforce CPQ (STEELBRICK)

Tags: cpq

How can i use product rule and price rule in salesforce CPQ. AnyOne have a example how to use and test the rules in salesforce?

Answer (score 3):

please refer to below documentations available in steelbrick community

[Product Rules](https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Products-Bundles-Knowledge-Base/An-Overview-of-Product-Rules/ta-p/85)

[Price Rules](https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Prices-Discounts-Knowledge-Base/Price-Rules/ta-p/166)